# Checking out a working copy results in missing files (showing status as marked for deletion) and strange behaviour when reverting

Tags: svn

I tried to check out a working copy of a branch of an svn respository into a local directory:

```
svn checkout svn+vm-ssh://svn.example.com/dev/support .
```

Not all files I am expecting to be checked out are checked out, and when I type `svn status`, it is reported that thousands of files are marked for deletion, e.g. these 3 files:

```
D       root/js/crossbrowser/x/xc/xc.h
D       root/js/crossbrowser/x/xc/xc.c
D       root/js/crossbrowser/x/xc/license.html
```

If I recreate these files manually, and `ls` in the directory, I can see that the files exist, but `svn status` reports the same as before – files marked for deletion. (I should at least expect status `R` in this case, no?)

If I run `svn revert license.html` in the directory, it appears to succeed (there is no error message), but again, `svn status` shows exactly the same thing – file marked for deletion.

Is there something obvious (or less obvious) that I am overlooking here? Why weren't all the expected files checked out from the repository? Why doesn't manual creation, or svn reverting, result in the expected svn status?

Comment: 1. What happens if you check out the working copy into a clean new directory? It seems to me that you check out into an existing directory that has some data. 2. What is the version of your Subversion client and server? 3. What is your client OS? 4. What is "svn+vm-ssh"? Is it some kind of custom protocol or a typo in "svn+ssh"?

Comment: @bahrep thanks for your comment. I tried the process again from the beginning today and got a svn error... "local unversioned, incoming add upon update". I did a little googling, and found [this page](http://tomhennigan.blogspot.com/2012/01/resolve-tree-conflict-svn-local.html) which resolved the issue for me. Not really sure what's going on TBH